# "Non-monic" integral closure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-extensions

Let $R\subset S$ be an extension of commutative rings.
The integral closure of $R$ in $S$ is $\textrm{IC}(R)=\{s\in S\mid \exists f(x)\in\ R[x]\text{ monic polynomial such that }f(s)=0\}$, which is a ring.

How about "non-monic" integral closure, namely, $$\textrm{NMIC}(R)=\{s\in S\mid \exists f(x)\in\ R[x]\text{ (possiboly non-monic) nonzero polynomial such that }f(s)=0\}?$$
It is obvious that $R\subset\textrm{IC}(R)\subset\textrm{NMIC}(R)\subset S$.
Is $\textrm{NMIC}(R)$ a ring, or an abelian group, or multiplicatively closed?
I read several books and searched in web, but I could not find any clue to this question.

Comment: Usually your "non-monic" integral extension is called an algebraic extension. The point is that in fields, algebraic extensions and monic extensions are clearly the same. In a general context of rings, an extension $R[x]$ is a finite extension of $R$ if $x$ is integral but not necessarily a finite extension if $x$ is simply algebraic.